# tool tip does not work correctly if text is more in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have widgets in my page, where each widget's width cannot exceed more than 400px. Data is completely driven from backend(I do not have any control on it).

The problem is if my tool tip's length is more than certain limit, it hides the data. Please see the screen shot attached to [my message on another forum](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=18401).

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: What is the status of this question? Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control where the tooltip displays using [**positioner**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip--positioner) like so:

```
tooltip: 
{
  positioner: function () 
  {
    return { x: 80, y: 50 };
  }
},
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/j88fD/) is a demonstration.  Then you could use the [**formatter**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#tooltip--formatter) to display the data in the tooltip properly so it does not extend past the width of your contorl.